# VS 2012 EF 5 using .net 4 and database first Layered applications concepts

Tags: entity-framework-5

I upgraded from VS2005 to VS2012 specifically to code in .Net 4,.Net 4.5, and use EF5.  I am new to EF. I have Julie's EF book but it talks mainly about EF4 and POCO and it has me confused trying to implement EF5.

My hosting only allows me to run .Net 4 currently.  I am trying to use EF5 on a new database.
I tried Code first to generate my database but I could not get it to generate the database.  So I created the database first and then generated the model from the database with EF5.  What I want is a layered website using ASP.NET Forms, Data Access Layer, and a Business Layer.  The business layer I intend to build so I can use ObjectDataSource to pull in to the webpage along with some web services to use cascading dropdowns.

I have my NameX.edm model created but the tt files don't have the same names, they have Model1.tt and Model1.Context.tt is not the same name, why.  Also Model1.Context.tt is empty.  I am attempting to create the POCO classes running the EF5 DbContext but I am having trouble getting it to see the edm model.  I read somewhere that EF5 creates the POCO automatically.  I am not seeing the big picture here.  Is my issue that I am not using .Net4.5?

What I have is a ASP.NET Application project, a EF Project, a POCO Project, and intend to have a forth project with the Business logic.  How do I get the EF generated correctly and the POCO classes?  I want a layered application for to scale well. Next question How to get the POCO classes to talk with the Business logic?  My database is SQL.  I am use to writing stored proceedures to accomplish everything through business logic.

Comment: If you target .NET Framework 4 EF will not by default generate POCO entities. I believe there are tt templates on VS gallery that you could use to replace the default code generation strategy to generate POCO instead of EntityObject based entities. Look for DbContext generator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Model First technique, make sure that you have references to *System.Data.Entity* and *System.Data.Entity.Design*. Also, you will need to create a reference to the EntityFramework.dll as well. It is located by default in *c:\Program Files\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Feature CTP5\Binaries\EntityFramework.dll*. If you can not find it, make sure you have installed the Entity Framework through your Package Manager Console. To do this, open up Tools, Library Package Manager, Package Manager Console, then type *Install-Package EntityFrameWork*.

Next you want to add a new item to your project. Right click on your solution, go to Add, then select New Item. You want to select Data from the Common Items section on the left, then select ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Next Select Generate From Database. In the next screen, if you have not set up your connection to the server, click *New Connection...*, otherwise select your database from the drop down box. You need to select whether or not you want to include your connection string information in your config file. This is up to you how secure you need your application to be. If you choose not to, you need to pass this information as parameters in code. Also at the bottom, you will most likely want to change the auto-generated entities name to something easier for you to use. This name will be the name of your DBContext Class!

Next you want to select the tables you would like EF to create POCO's for. If you want all the tables just tick the tables items. Same goes for views and stored procs.

Once you click finish, then you should see all your fancy POCOS laid out in front of you in Design Mode. **Note** If you do not have primary keys in place for all your tables, I suggest you fix that! VS will spit at you if you do not have Primary Keys set, or if your naming conventions in your tables prevent VS from creating them for you implicitly.

This is a quick little tutorial on getting you up and running. You can now persist and pull data from your POCOS by using your DBContext object. For example if you named your DBContext class *Gary_Bettman_Sucks*, and you wanted to create a new record from your table called *NHL* you would do the following:

```
Dim context as New Gary_Bettman_Sucks

Dim PullMyGoalie as New NHL With {
    .Goals = 0,
    .Playoffs = False
}

context.Set(Of NHL).Add(PullMyGoalie)
context.SaveChanges()
```

I would **Highly** suggest you look into implementing the Repository Pattern with your design to encourage code re-use, and it will seriously make your life MUCH easier down the road.

Hope this helps!